# linear mixed model random effects structure

Tags: r, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I am having some difficulties with a linear mixed model implementation.

The situation:

- 17 subjects get tested on both sides of their body (L vs R) at 5 different time points (i1-i5) with 2 tests (A vs B)
- I want to test whether there is a difference in the values obtained by the 2 tests, correcting for repeated measurements per subject and for the side of the body.

My data is

```
df <- structure(list(test = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), patient = c(55L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 
53L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 
46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 
38L, 36L, 36L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 
50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 
44L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 55L, 55L, 
54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 
48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 
39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 
52L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 
45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 
36L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 
49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 41L, 
41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 
53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 
47L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 
38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 
51L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 
44L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 55L, 
55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 
48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 
40L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 
52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 
46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 
36L, 36L, 55L, 55L, 54L, 54L, 53L, 53L, 52L, 52L, 51L, 51L, 50L, 
50L, 49L, 49L, 48L, 48L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 44L, 
41L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 36L, 36L), side = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("L", "R"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(168, 230.6, 196.8, 235.5, 176.9, 120.3, 177.4, 
    165.5, 175.7, 324.7, 218.6, 342.4, 310.7, 98, 198.5, 315, 
    122.7, 399.9, 399.7, 375.7, 328.5, 342, 307.6, 227.5, 221.3, 
    323, 143, 331.6, 131.1, 333.2, 283.7, 185.4, 219.1, 212.1, 
    174, 229.3, 178.1, 238.6, 185.1, 118.6, 152.3, 190.2, 184.8, 
    328, 216.8, 306.2, 301.2, 96.1, 199.4, 334, 144.3, 380.7, 
    416, 334.9, 328.4, 307.2, 273.8, 226.1, 240.4, 229.7, 134.9, 
    302, 122.7, 342.1, 275.2, 170.4, 184.4, 199.6, 133.9, 233.2, 
    170.8, 241.6, 135.2, 111, 132.2, 166, 153.6, 323.5, 199.8, 
    335.1, 292, 102.2, 178, 319, 107.5, 395, 348.8, 360.3, 305, 
    318.7, 265.1, 202.9, 209.4, 249.3, 153.3, 316.4, 152.2, 315, 
    226.7, 174.7, 205.2, 211, 134.8, 222.7, 158.1, 239, 135.7, 
    122, 138.8, 191.3, 161.8, 332.7, 179.9, 308.9, 275.6, 93.7, 
    172, 326, 127, 380, 366, 341.4, 300.2, 307.3, 240.2, 224, 
    224.1, 175.2, 138.7, 299.7, 104, 276.4, 252.2, 172.3, 167.8, 
    202.9, 133.5, 229.1, 176, 235.7, 133, 118, 130.9, 163.8, 
    154.5, 324.1, 202.2, 326.5, 284.1, 100.6, 175, 325, 86.3, 
    391.6, 358.2, 330.2, 286.1, 325, 254.8, 195.6, 186.4, 153.3, 
    157.6, 333.1, 159.8, 293, 234.3, 150.8, 181.6, 205.4, 122.1, 
    227.7, 159, 241, 127.8, 119.3, 128.3, 187.9, 162, 324, 195, 
    309.7, 276.4, 92.2, 182, 325, 107, 374, 352.3, 326.5, 274.2, 
    309.5, 248.3, 211.4, 216.4, 164.2, 150.3, 313.1, 129.6, 283.1, 
    255.3, 146.6, 159.5, 198, 146.5, 226.5, 179.5, 242.6, 160.9, 
    121.4, 146.9, 167.8, 176.7, 327, 198.5, 330.4, 290.6, 99, 
    188, 323, 114.8, 393, 361.9, 336.9, 334, 316.4, 309.8, 184, 
    226.4, 159.1, 185.2, 309.2, 187.1, 232.8, 265.9, 150.8, 220.1, 
    203.5, 158.1, 225.3, 166.8, 242.8, 145.6, 110.3, 137.2, 186.6, 
    183.8, 327, 189.3, 309.7, 286.2, 99.6, 188, 332, 129.2, 365, 
    398.6, 332.4, 329.2, 299.2, 275, 189, 229.7, 151.8, 189.9, 
    313.9, 164, 272.4, 264.9, 157.9, 185.8, 200.3, 164.3, 239.4, 
    190.1, 244.4, 175.8, 124.5, 181.6, 173.8, 178, 322, 211.4, 
    336.7, 309.3, 95.2, 191.1, 315, 112.5, 397.6, 381.8, 355.2, 
    320, 316.7, 310.2, 170.6, 223.9, 154.6, 181.9, 318.5, 188.9, 
    222.2, 282.5, 159.4, 218.2, 204, 168.1, 232.2, 177.4, 245.4, 
    176.2, 117.7, 155.4, 187.8, 185.4, 332, 212.8, 308.8, 298.2, 
    99.7, 198, 334, 137.3, 381, 400.8, 339.6, 322.1, 290.5, 278.3, 
    224.2, 237, 146.8, 182.2, 309.4, 163.1, 269.3, 268.9, 151.6, 
    195, 199.5)), .Names = c("test", "subject", "side", "time", 
"value"), row.names = c(NA, -340L), class = "data.frame")
```

I fit this using

```
df.fit1 <- lme(value ~ test + side, random = ~side|subject, data = df)
summary(df.fit1)
```

I used the `lme` function from the `nlme` package to test with the test and side as fixed effects. I am pretty sure about this part, but I am in doubt how to code the random effect part. I used `~ side|subject`, but I am unsure. I want to correct for multiple tests per patient, but I don't know how to incorporate the correction for side in this (random = 1|side + 1|patient? or do I need to test the interaction side:patient)?

Also, is it statistically correct to test at which time points there is a significant difference between the two tests? Can I just use a paired t-test for that?

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: The `lme4` package provides the `lmer()` function. The `nlme` package provides the `lme()` function. It's a little unlcear what function/package you were using or want to use.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for your remark! I initially tried lme4, but I switched to nlme, as the syntax seemed easier to me. I updated my question.

Comment: Your proposed model seems to include `side` in a reasonable way, but I'm concerned about your time points. If those were not chosen randomly and differently for each subject, you might have another fixed or a crossed random effect.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks for your comment! The time points are the same for each subject with equal intervals in between them. In my opinion, the effect of time of the measurements is not predictable and random, so we could include time as an additional random effect?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know enough about the experiment, but you definitely should try to include time in your model. A random effect might be reasonable if a specific time point can be expected to somehow impact the outcome (example: you administer a drug to patients in the morning and measure after 1, 2, 6, 12, 24 hours). You can then check (with AIC and a likelihood ratio test) whether such a random effect would improve the model. It might also be reasonable to include time as a fixed effect (e.g., as a factor using polynomial contrasts).